# Multi-lingual site with a splash (language select screen) at the root

Tags: localization, language

I'm trying to get something working and I keep breaking my internal links doing it.

Here's what I'd like:

public/index.html (this page would be the language select screen and can be dealt with outside the cms)

public/fr/index.php (craft loader for french)
public/en/index.php (craft loader for english)

I would also like the CP to load from the root.  I thought of having it redirect to a "craft.php" page that would be the loader if the requested file doesn't exist, and it worked for the CP.  But of course, it grabs any of the calls to the site that is not fr/ or en/ only.  As soon as there's something else in the uri, it goes to 404.

Any idea for this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that was easy enough.  I had forgotten about the `.htaccess` in the subfolders.  Everything works like planned now.

`public/.htaccess` (redirects to craft.php if file doesn't exist)
`public/index.html` (splash page)
`public/craft.php` (craft loader)

`public/fr/.htaccess` (redirects to index.php if file doesn't exist)
`public/fr/index.php` (craft loader for french)

`public/en/.htaccess` (redirects to index.php if file doesn't exist)
`public/en/index.php` (craft loader for english)